# I want to export sql XAMPP, but format is html?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

[This i want to export my Database SQL, but format change to html automatic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obMsS.jpg)

> I want to export my SQL database on phpmyadmin, but the format changed to html automaticaly

Comment: see https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/wamp/administration/export-database/

Comment: I have done with this tutorial, but the format still changes to html automaticaly